# Hyperbolic honeycombs

Tags: 3d, hyperbolic-geometry, tessellations

I am puzzling with hyperbolic honeycombs or space filling stacking of hyperbolic regular polyhedrons and it looks all very complex to me .

As far as I tried I could not even find a stacking where two faces of different polyhedrons  share the same plane.

So the only conditions I have are: 
* the polyhedrons together are space filling
* all polyhedrons are regular 
(So this means all edges are the same size and the faces are equilateral triangles, squares , Pentagon's,  ect)

Does this allready imply that no two faces are in the same plane?

Is this correct or am I overlooking the obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $P$ is a regular dodecahedron whose dihedral angles are right angles, then the group $G$ generated by reflections in the sides of $P$ is properly discontinuous, $P$ is a fundamental domain for $G$, and the $G$-translates of $P$ form a tiling of hyperbolic 3-space (what you call a "honeycomb" or a "space filling stacking"). This is an immediate application of the Poincare polyhedron theorem.

Furthermore, since the dihedral angles are right angles, the plane through every face of $P$ is tiled by faces of $G$-translates of $P$. This is quite the opposite behavior to what your question asserts, namely that no two faces of the tiling lie on the same plane.